# Adding an array of div IDs to a var so I have animate multiple divs across site

Tags: javascript

I found some js on github that did what I needed it to do with the exception of being able to have multiple hand/glove animations on different pages of the site. The original js called the div ID and I assumed that the var needed an array of the existing div IDs.  I tried that and it did not work. I am not a js or jquery guru at all but I can implement and tweak most of the time.

I have set up a fiddle so you can see how the original js is working with my code. I just need both div containers to animate the corresponding PNG that is called in the css for the separate div IDs.

http://jsfiddle.net/haagmeister/38LB2/14/

The code pulled from the CMS and the second div is not animating.. I assume it is because the calling of the var is not set up properly to pull from the array?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#new-headers-container{
width: 1024px;
height: 430px;
border: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#sports-gloves-container{
width: 411px;
height: 430px;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
background: url('http://popticals.com/template/sportHeaders/circle-animation.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
border: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#golf-glove{
width: 284px;
height: 430px;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
background: url('http://popticals.com/template/sportHeaders/gloves/golf-glove.png') no-repeat 0 0;
border: none;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 86px;
padding: 0;
}
#bike-glove{
width: 284px;
height: 430px;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
background: url('http://popticals.com/template/sportHeaders/gloves/bike-glove.png') no-repeat 0 0;
border: none;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 86px;
padding: 0;
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
(function($) {

        // you should change these variables
        var numberOfSteps = 5;
        var heightOfOneStep = 430;
        var idOfAnimatedDiv = ["golf-glove","bike-glove"];
        var timeBetweenSteps = 60;

        // you probably won't have to change these
        var index = -1;
        var direction = "+";
        var steps = [];
        var timeOutDuration;


        // instantiate steps with the correct heights of the PNG
        for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfSteps - 1; i++) {
            steps.push( heightOfOneStep * i );
        }

        var interval = setTimeout(function() {

            // reset timeOutDuration
            if ( timeOutDuration != timeBetweenSteps ) {
                timeOutDuration = timeBetweenSteps;
            }

            // increment or decrement index
            if ( direction == "+" ) {
                index++;
            } else {
                index--;    
            }

            // reverse direction if we are at the beginning or end of the animation
            if (index == numberOfSteps) {

               direction = "-";
               timeOutDuration = 10000;

            } else if ( index == -1 ) {

                direction = "+";
                timeOutDuration = 750;

            }


            $('#' + idOfAnimatedDiv ).css('backgroundPosition', '0px -' + steps[index] + 'px');

            setTimeout(arguments.callee, timeOutDuration);

        }, 1000);

    })(jQuery);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="sports-gloves-container">
    <div id="golf-glove"></div>
</div>
<div id="sports-gloves-container">
    <div id="bike-glove"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are trying to use an array of ids there, so you need to make the transition for both ids. Change this:

```
        for(var j=0;j<idOfAnimatedDiv.length;j++){
            $('#' + idOfAnimatedDiv[j] ).css('backgroundPosition', '0px -' + steps[index] + 'px');
        }
```